# Mongo collection doc organisation and query

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have logbook documents with a list of logs embedded:

```
{ 
    type:'logbook',
    name:'my book',
    userRef:2,
    cdate: ....,
    logs: [
      { 
          color: 'red',
          weight: 200,
          cdate: ...,
          foo: 'bar'
      },
      { 
          color: 'blue',
          weight: 100,
          cdate: ...,
          foo: 'bar'
      },
      { 
          color: 'green',
          weight: 240,
          cdate: ...,
          foo: 'bar'
      }
    ]
```

I would like to show paginated ordered log entries for a given logbook.

Is it possible to extract those from such a structure with mongo ?

If not should I have a logEntries collection for logs instead ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify which parts of a document you want to retrieve by using [field selection](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Querying#Querying-FieldSelection). To select part of an array field, you can use the [`$slice` operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Retrieving+a+Subset+of+Fields#RetrievingaSubsetofFields-RetrievingaSubrangeofArrayElements), for example:

```
// select the name and a range of log entries from the document
db.logbooks.find({ name: "my book" }, { name: 1, logs: { $slice: [10, 5] } })
```

Note that any sorting of the log entries besides insertion order has to be done client-side.

Comment: Hum ok if I want to keep it ordered maybe I should sort logbook.logs before writing everytime I update/save a logbook doc.

Comment: @coulix: If you add new log entries to a logbook with the [`$push` operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-%24push), the log entries will be ordered by insertion time. If you need other ways of sorting, besides date sorting, you're better off storing the log entries in a separate collection.